# How to use @SessionScope beans with Vaadin Broadcaster?

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, broadcast, session-scope

I am using Spring Boot and Vaadin Flow (latest). And I tried the broadcaster example and it works. But as soon as I try to pass the received message to a @SessionScope annotated bean, I am getting an exception

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request`

Any hints on this? Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: I don't use the collaboration engine but I doubt that you can access the Vaadin Session without a HTTP request. That's also what the error message is saying. Why do you want to reference a session scoped bean?

Comment: It really seems to be a problem with spring sessions mixed with vaadin. I thought it's a common use case to take the result of a broadcast you received and put it into a session to process it. But i am still using sessions wrong. It's just that I can't get it right ... For now.

Comment: At best it would work with `@VaadinSessionScope`?  But this is all
guesswork until we see some code of what you are trying...  Please
provide
a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's happening according to my understanding: Spring's `@SessionScope` beans are created for each HTTP Session, or as the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html) says,

> [@SessionScope] Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a HTTP Session. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.

This means you need to be working in the context of an HTTP session, and as the error message says,

> No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request?

The [example implementation](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/advanced/server-push#push.broadcaster.broadcaster) of the Broadcaster pattern uses a simple background thread executor created by the `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`- the thread doesn't know anything about HTTP requests or sessions, and it's specifically not `running in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.`.

Your actual problem isn't visible in the question, but hopefully, this answer clarifies the error you're getting and helps you move forward.